# read from .txt the third coordinate using c++

Tags: c++, coordinates

I have a .txt file with the real coordinates of points. The scenario is the camera facing a wall; between them I have a box.
I want to get in the .txt only the points refering to the box, so I want to read the third component from coordinates, meaning depth value and if it's bigger than a certain distance to supprime all the line.

file.txt

0.005545 0.06564 **1.6354**

0.235443 0.35464 **2.6575**

if(value>2.5)
{
   delete line from .txt completely
}

all the coordinates are separated with a white space and lines with an intro.

thanks

Comment: What is it that you want help with?

Comment: the method to access to the file content

Comment: What about using the `cut` or `awk` command line tools to preprocess your data before reading it in your c++ application?

Comment: I am not completely certain but I think the `std::stringstream` provides exactly this. You can then read each token. `float one, two, three; stream >> one >> two >> three;` From that on you could easily implement you logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

#define THRESH 2.5f

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<float> DataArray;

    ifstream myfile("test.txt"); 

    copy(istream_iterator<float>(myfile),
         istream_iterator<float>(),
         back_inserter(DataArray));
    myfile.close();

    ofstream newfile("test.txt");

    for(int i = 2; i < DataArray.size(); i += 3)
    {
        if(DataArray[i] < THRESH)
        {
            for (int j = i-2; j <= i; ++j)
                newfile << DataArray[j] << "  ";
            newfile << endl;
        }
    }

    myfile.close(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i've just changed DataArray[i] < THRESH to do as I explained but it works. thanks!

Comment: @ali ouhh, I misunderstood, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `std::ifstream` to read from a file.

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream input_file;

input_file.open("input_file.txt");

// Read the file one line at a time
while (std::getline(input_file, line))
{
    // Do your thing
}

input_file.close();
```

Hint: Write a new file and rename later.

Comment: Thanks! but how can I compare the third coordinate with a value in order to decide if I delete the line or not?

Comment: You will have to tokenize the line based on a delimiter(space in your case), extract the right token(3rd in your case) and cast it to the correct type for comparison. Please have a look at `boost::tokenizer` and `boost::lexical_cast`.